# Atmosphere Client not receiving message?

Tags: atmosphere

***I have made a jersey atmosphere service
When i am trying to subscribe the topic its get connected but its not receiving messages***

i am trying to send messages from java client to javascript client

Server Code

```
@Path("/pubsub/{topic}")
public class Eventer {


        private
        @PathParam("topic")
        Broadcaster topic;

        @GET
        public SuspendResponse<String> subscribe() {
            return new SuspendResponse.SuspendResponseBuilder<String>()
                    .broadcaster(topic)
                    .outputComments(true)
                    .addListener(new EventsLogger())
                    .build();
        }

        @POST
        @Broadcast
        @Produces("text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1")
        public Broadcastable publish(@FormParam("message") String message) {
            return new Broadcastable(message, "", topic);
        }

}
```

JavaScript client

```
var myName = false;
    var author = null;
    var logged = false;
    var socket = $.atmosphere;
    var subSocket;
    var transport = 'websocket';
    var fallbackTransport = 'long-polling'
    var connected = false;
    var uuid = 0;
 function connect() {
        // We are now ready to cut the request
        var request = { url: 'http://localhost:8888/factory/factory/pubsub/Light_FF_Bath_Ceiling' ,

            transport: transport,


            fallbackTransport: fallbackTransport};

        request.onOpen = function (response) {
        alert('onOpen');
        };

        request.onReopen = function (response) {
           alert('onReopen');
        };

        request.onMessage = function (response) {
            alert(response);

        };

        request.onClose = function (response) {
            subSocket.push(JSON.stringify({ author: author, message: 'disconnecting' }));
        };

        request.onError = function (response) {
          alert('onError');
        };

        request.onReconnect = function (request, response) {

        };

        subSocket = socket.subscribe(request);
    }

connect();
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container, 
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e194 -->
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
    version="3.0"> 
     <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
    <display-name>AtmosphereServlet</display-name>
   <servlet>
        <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
        <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

        <!-- If you want to use Servlet 3.0 -->
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <!-- List of init-param --> 
    </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
        <!-- Any mapping -->
        <url-pattern>/factory/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```